# Implementation of std::reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, reference, reference-wrapper

While looking at the implementation of `std::reference_wrapper`
[here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

The constructors and operators are obvious to me but I didn't understand this part

```
template< class... ArgTypes >
typename std::result_of<T&(ArgTypes&&...)>::type
  operator() ( ArgTypes&&... args ) const {
  return std::invoke(get(), std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);
}
```

Could someone simplify it for me ... would be appreciated

Edit: and would be great to give useful example for `operator()` of `std::reference_wrapper`

Comment: Basically, it forwards `operator()` to the referee Functor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This defines the `operator()` member function, which is applicable for an `std::reference_wrapper` wrapping a reference to a Callable. The purpose of it is to call the underlying Callable.

- The template parameter `class ... Args` is to make it generic in terms of the parameters that can be passed to the underlying Callable.
- The return type of the operator has to be the return type produced by invoking the Callable, which is obtained by the `typename std::result_of<T&(ArgTypes&&...)>::type` part
- It uses the `invoke` call as a general-purpose way of calling the Callable, which works irrespective of what type of Callable it is (Functor, function pointer, member function pointer etc).
- It uses `std::forward` in passing the argument list to achieve [perfect forwarding](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c/) - so for example lvalue and rvalues passed in to the original call retain their l/rvalue-ness in the underlying call.

Comment: could you give an example for operator() of std::reference_wrapper